# A property holds generically for polynomials - meaning?

Tags: polynomials

I have a trouble with understanding the definition of "generic". I would be thankful if you can help me to make it clear. I will give a formal definition, intuitive explanation and an example:

A property is said to **hold generically** for polynomials $f_1, . . . , f_n$ of degree at most $d_1, . . . , d_n$ if there is a nonzero polynomial in the coefficients of the $f_i$ such that the property holds for all $f_1, . . . , f_n$ for which the polynomial is nonvanishing.

Intuitively, a property of polynomials is generic if it holds for “most”
polynomials $f_1, . . . , f_n$. Our definition makes this precise by defining
“most” to mean that some polynomial in the coefficients of the $f_i$ is nonvanishing.

As a simple example, consider a single polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$.
We claim that the property “$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has two solutions, counting
multiplicity” holds generically. To prove this, we must find a polynomial
in the coefficients $a, b, c$ whose nonvanishing implies the desired property.
Here, the condition is easily seen to be $a \neq 0$ over the complex numbers.

I still don't understand the meaning of generic. Okey, so what if the property holds for example for $f_1,...,f_{n-1}$ and does not hold for $f_n$. How do we define that new nonzero polynomial and what does it need to hold for it (so that our property holds generically for $f_1,..f_n$)?

P.S. meaning of nonvanishing - it can't be $0$ for any value of variables. Am I right?

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=zoDHCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=generic+polynomial+algebraic+geometry&source=bl&ots=bI0ibKq5f1&sig=p69KC0eepIJ-lm1DuT0TxY0IIMY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie9t_Ll4DYAhUK2WMKHe2qAM0Q6AEIajAJ#v=onepage&q=generic%20polynomial%20algebraic%20geometry&f=false) gives a small intuitive explaination which may help.

Comment: [This](https://books.google.com/books?id=U4bdBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=generic+polynomial+algebraic+geometry+intuition&source=bl&ots=TOev-JTRWp&sig=_o6xzB7UMPMUCFKLVhsEKNg2jsE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSvdLUmIDYAhVB_WMKHXWdATYQ6AEIYTAJ#v=onepage&q=generic%20polynomial%20algebraic%20geometry%20intuition&f=false) may be what your example is from, but the second example in it may be useful.

Comment: Yes, my example is from "Using algebraic geometry".
As far as I understood, "generically" means "with some conditions". 
In the example: ax^2+bx+c=0 has generically two solutions means it has for every polynomial but with the condition that a is not 0.

Comment: My reading of this is that "A property $P$ holds generically for a collection of polynomials $\{f_1,\dots, f_n\}$ if there exists some other polynomial $q$ _in the coefficients of the $f_i$_ such that $q(\vec{c_i})\neq 0\implies$ $P$ holds for $f_i$", where $c_i$ are the coefficients of $f_i$.  The two examples illustrate this well in my opinion, but I don't have enough familiarity with this to give a true answer to it.

Comment: It appears to me that "holding generically" is meant to formalize "holding for sets of polynomials with algeraically independent coefficients", which motivates why it's used to model "random" polynomials.